# "C-3" vs "C-u 3-" in spacemacs

Tags: prefix-argument

I'am using spacemacs and I was reading this [5.2.1 TODO keywords as workflow](https://orgmode.org/manual/Workflow-states.html) in the org manual and it says that to set a specific state right way the sequence of keys `C-3 C-c C-t` can be used.

If I hit the control key and the 3 key at the same time it shows me `C-u 3-` and I can't seem to figure out how to do it as `C-3`. It still works though.
Should I just ignore this and remember it's the same or is there a way to type it as `C-3`?

Comment: You are seeing `C-u 3-` in the echo area because Emacs is interpreting your `C-3` as a prefix argument. In that context it is the same as `C-u 3`, and the final hyphen lets you know that Emacs is waiting for more. It's waiting for a key sequence in order to look up its command and apply the prefix numeric argument (`3`) to that command while invoking it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer: My answer pertains to vanilla Emacs features and default keybindings. The concepts should be the same in Spacemacs, but the default bindings may differ.

> If I hit the control key and the 3 key at the same time it shows me `C-u 3-` and I can't seem to figure out how to do it as `C-3`. It still works though. Should I just ignore this and remember it's the same or is there a way to type it as `C-3`?

For most practical purposes they're the same thing, subject to the [type of terminal](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Terminal-Type.html) you're on, i.e. how modifier keys are interpreted.

See [`(emacs) Arguments`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Arguments.html) for the whole shebang, particularly the last paragraph:

```
   On graphical displays, ‘C-0’, ‘C-1’, etc. act the same as ‘M-0’,
‘M-1’, etc.
```

Note also the following distinction between plain <kbd>C-u</kbd> and numeric <kbd>C-N</kbd>/<kbd>M-N</kbd> (for some integer `N`) arguments:

```
   A few commands treat a plain ‘C-u’ differently from an ordinary
argument.  A few others may treat an argument of just a minus sign
differently from an argument of −1.  These unusual cases are described
when they come up; they exist to make an individual command more
convenient, and they are documented in that command’s documentation
string.
```

See also [`(elisp) Prefix Command Arguments`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Prefix-Command-Arguments.html) for the nitty gritty details.